# Atomic execution of a statement block

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I have a sequence of statements that I want to run atomically. For simplicity let's say they are enclosed in a block statement:

```
{
    // statements...
}
```

Is there any **straightforward** way to do such a thing in C++14?

To clarify, I want this block to be executed as if it is only one atomic operation. I don't have a critical section to protect with a mutex. The problem is that the bundled operations should get executed after each other without multiple context switches between the first and the last statements in the sequence.

Comment: Not yet. Plans for future. Use `std::unique_lock` for now.

Comment: @DeiDei how is this possible in any future C++ without the facilities of a real-time kernel to prevent interrupts and thread scheduling during the atomic block?

Comment: @RichardCritten Take a look at [N4514](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4514.pdf). It proposes `synchronized` and `atomic` blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "straightforward".  I think [std::unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) is pretty straightward to use.

```
{
    std::unique_lock lock(m_mutex);
    // sequence of operations

    // lock destructor will release mutex
}
```

The only problem is that any *other* places that manipulate the variables protected by the mutex must *also* do the same.

**Edit**

To answer the clarified question: **No**.

To prevent context switches you will have to use a proper Real Time Operating System (RTOS), and use its facilities.  If you are running under a general purpose OS like Linux or Windows (the visual-studio tag suggests the latter), there are various platform specific calls you can make which will make context switches less likely - but you can't prevent them.

(Context switches become less likely if you run in kernel-mode, but even then it's hard to stop interrupt handlers and page-fault handlers cutting in.)

Comment: Are you sure the OP is okay with mutual exclusion rather than true atomicity?

Comment: Nope.  But *true* atomicity will involve in kernel mode (and is outside the scope of C++)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited the question, take a look please.

Comment: @MartinBonner : Maybe _that_'s the real answer here... ;-]

Answer (score 3):

The issue is: Transactional memory. A transaction is an action that has the properties *Atomicity*, *Consistency*, *Isolation*, and *Durability* (ACID). *Atomicity*: Either all or no statement of the block is performed. *Consistency*: The system is always in a consistent state. All transactions build a total order. *Isolation*: Each transaction runs in total isolation from the other transactions.

*"A transaction is a kind of a speculative action that is only committed if the initial state holds. It is in contrast to a mutex an optimistic approach. A transaction is performed without synchronisation. It will only be published if no conflict to its initial state happens. A mutex is a pessimistic approach. At first, the mutex ensures that no other thread can enter the critical region. The thread only will enter the critical region if it is the exclusive owner of the mutex and, hence, all other threads are blocked."* - [Rainer Grimm](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/transactional-memory)

Transactional memory is supported by GCC as of version 6.1 (requires -fgnu-tm to enable). [(reference)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory)

Comment: The answer could be improved, and made relevant to the C++ question, by answering what the status of support for transactional memory in C++ specifically is, (i.e. only at [technical specification stage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory)). It looks like the proposed `synchronized` keyword will in time answer the question precisely, but currently it's unsupported in the standard. Then it would be a good answer.

Comment: @acraig5075 Transactional memory is supported by GCC as of version 6.1  (requires -fgnu-tm to enable). Synchronized blocks behave such as they are protected by a global lock, are **not** transactions, and may call transaction-unsafe functions. A transaction is performed without synchronization. Atomic blocks are available in the forms: `atomic_noexcept`, `atomic_commit`, and `atomic_cancel`. The three suffixes `_noexcept, _commit`, and `_cancel` defines how an atomic block should manage an exception [(reference)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory).

Comment: Everything you say is great, I'm not arguing. I'm saying edit the question and add C++ relevance. I've added this for you.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I've upvoted it but it requires a code snippet to be accepted as the answer. Thank you again.